# A details event side bar that appears when I click on the event card

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am displaying events on my app like cards. When I click on the card, I need a side bar fixed on the right side to open and disappear when I click on the close button.
The side bar in example:
[image: side bar example]

How can I implement this in react?

Comment: use a display : block css property and toggle it with react

Comment: between block and none?

Comment: yes. you can add a keyframe to make to the sidebar appearing smoothly

Comment: I have three divs that are in flex. The cards, the side information and the third one will be this side bar. It is not overflowing on the page, it is pushing everything to the side

Comment: `z-index: 1;` on the side bar maybe? This will place it above all the other content.